# Partial loading before the controller : Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, controller

In my index.html I have a sidebar that needs to be displayed only for certain views and not for all. So this sidebar is inside index.html and below it is the ng-view div. Also a global controller is associated with the body tag.

```
<body ng-controller='init'>
<div class='sidebar' ng-show='sidedisplay'>
</div>
<div ng-view=''></div>
</body>
```

Inside my init controller by default I have : `$scope.sidedisplay = false; console.log('Here');`

Now when I run the project, the html loads and I see the sidebar and then after some 4-5 seconds i get `here` in the console log and the sidebar disappears. Why is the controller loading so much later than the HTML?? How can i rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make use of [ng-cloak](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak).

Comment: I still see the side bar. now for 1-2 seconds

Comment: I applied the ng-cloak to the body

Comment: You may need to include some additional detail.

Comment: Like the code of your controller perhaps? You might also want to look into why it takes 4-5 seconds before your controller is even initialized.

Comment: Did you also apply the CSS that is suggested in the ng-cloak documentation?